# Batch to insert a line in a text file

Tags: batch-file

My goal is to make a script which is able to insert a string under a specific line. This is what I have done:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION


set outputFile=C:\Utilisateurs\a669884\Documents\script22.txt
set "_strInsert=import java.interceptor.ReportInterceptor;"
set "_strFind=import javax.interceptor.Interceptors;"


:Ask
echo Are you in the good folder (wlp-cas-provider)?(Y/N)
set INPUT=
set /P INPUT=Type input: %=%
If /I "%INPUT%"=="y" goto yes 
If /I "%INPUT%"=="n" goto no
echo Incorrect input & goto Ask

:yes

for %%i in (*.java) DO (
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%A IN ("%%i") DO (
  Echo %%A | Find "%_strFind%" && ECHO %%A>>"%outputFile%" && ECHO %_strInsert%>>"%outputFile%"
  IF [!errorlevel!] == [1] ECHO %%A>>"%outputFile%"
)
MOVE /Y "%outputFile%" "%%i" && DEL /F /Q "%outputFile%"
)

:no 
echo Oh no! Go to the right folder and comeback
cls
pause
```

The main idea is to copy the modified text in a temporary file and paste it in the original file. After that, the temporary file is deleted.

The code is working perfectly when it's done on only one file. With the `for` in order to do it on all `.java` files in a folder, it's not working anymore. The temporary file `script22.txt` is not deleted anymore and the text is piled up in it.

Comment: Although your code appears a little over-complicated to me, I cannot find any logical errors why your loop should fail, but I suspect the pipe is causing the unexpected behaviour. Anyway, you should delete the temporary file in advance as you are appending to it, but you do not need to delete it after the `move` command as it should no longer be there anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something along these lines: *(untested)*

```bat
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%A IN ("%CD%") DO IF /I NOT "%%~nxA"=="wlp-cas-provider" (
    ECHO=Please change directory to wlp-cas-provider
    ECHO= before running this script again.
    ECHO=
    ECHO=Press any key to exit ...
    PAUSE>NUL
    GOTO :EOF)

SET "_strFind=import javax.interceptor.Interceptors;"
SET "_strInsert=import java.interceptor.ReportInterceptor;"

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET NL=^


SET "str2Add=%_strFind%!NL!%_strInsert%"

FOR /F "TOKENS=1-2* DELIMS=:" %%A IN ('FINDSTR/BLINC:"%_strFind%" *.java 2^>NUL'
) DO (SET/A "i=1+%%B"
    FINDSTR/BLINC:"%_strInsert%" "%%A"|FINDSTR/B "!i!:">NUL
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ((  FOR /F "TOKENS=1* DELIMS=:" %%D IN ('FINDSTR/N $ "%%A"'
            ) DO IF %%D EQU %%B (ECHO=!str2Add!) ELSE ECHO=%%E)>>"%%A.tmp"))

FOR %%A IN (*.java.tmp) DO IF EXIST "%%~nA" (DEL "%%~nA" && REN "%%A" "%%~nA")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help , i'm a beginner in batch script so i'm a little bit lost. I just test this and it seems to work fine. God bless you

Answer (score 0):

There is no heavy logical error in your script why the loop should fail. I suspect it is the pipe `|` that is causing the unexpected behaviour, because it initiates a new command prompt (`cmd`) instance for either side, where the left one receives an already expanded string (`echo %%A`), which may contain characters that have special meanings to `cmd`.

Here is a possible improvement of your script -- see all the explanatory remarks (`rem`):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "targetFolder=C:\Utilisateurs\wlp-cas-provider"
set "fileMask=*.java"
set "outputFile=C:\Utilisateurs\a669884\Documents\script22.txt"
set "_strInsert=import java.interceptor.ReportInterceptor;"
set "_strFind=import javax.interceptor.Interceptors;"

rem // Enumerate all matching files:
for %%I in ("%targetFolder%\%fileMask%") do (
    rem /* Redirect the output of the whole `for /F` loop at once;
    rem    this improves the performance, and there is no appending `>>`,
    rem    so it does not matter whether the file already exists before: */
    > "%outputFile%" (
        rem /* Use `findstr /N` to precede every line by its line number
        rem    and a colon, so no line appears empty to `for /F` any more;
        rem    remember that `for /F` ignores empty lines otherwise: */
        for /F "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /N "^" "%%~I"') do (
            rem // Store the current line string with line number prefix:
            set "line=%%A"
            rem // Toggle delayed expansion to maintain exclamation marks:
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            rem // Remove the line number prefix and the colon:
            set "line=!line:*:=!"
            rem // Return the original line unconditionally:
            echo(!line!
            rem /* Explicitly initiate another child `cmd` instance on the
            rem    left side of the pipe with delayed expansion enabled;
            rem    escape the delayed expansion like `^^!` not to be
            rem    processed by the parent `cmd` instance, so the child
            rem    `cmd` instance receives the variable `!line!` only;
            rem    therefore strings potentially containing special
            rem    characters are expanded at the very latest point: */
            (cmd /V /C echo(^^!line^^!| find "!_strFind!" > nul) && (
                rem /* The string to search has been found, so return the
                rem    string to insert after it at this point: */
                echo(!_strInsert!
            )
            endlocal
        )
    )
    rem // Move the result file over the currently iterated one:
    move /Y "%outputFile%" "%%~I" > nul
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

This allows literally all characters to appear in the search string. Note that quotation marks `"` need to be doubled to be processed correctly by `find`. If you want the whole line to match the search string, replace the `find` command line by `findstr /X /C:"!_strFind!"`. In this case, if quotation marks appear in the search string, escape them like `\"`; literal backslashes need to be doubled like `\\`. Add the `/I` option to `find` or `findstr` if you want to search case-insensitively.

---

You can avoid the block containing the pipe...:

```cmd
            (cmd /V /C echo(^^!line^^!| find "!_strFind!" > nul) && (
                echo(!_strInsert!
            )
```

...when you use `if` statements to compare strings.

For example, use this instead if the line is expected to contain the search string:

```cmd
            if not "!line!"=="!line:*%_strFind%=!" echo(!_strInsert!
```

This always does a case-insensitive search because of the used [sub-string replacement](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) approach. This method may fail if any of the following characters occur in the search string: `^`, `!`, `%`, `=`, `"`.

If the whole line is expected to match the search string, use this instead:

```cmd
            if "!line!"=="!_strFind!" echo(!_strInsert!
```

This does a case-sensitive search, unless you add the `/I` switch to the `if` statement.